# HTML: Form upload file

Tags: html

I´m trying to create a form in HTML5 to upload a file to the server.
My HTML code is the following

```html
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  Select file to upload:
  <input type='file' name='fileToUploadNep'>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'></form>;
```

but as output i get this

[image]

there is no way to select the file from the harddisk.
can someone please help me ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. What browser are you using? Is there any odd styling going on?

Comment: I have copied your markup into a snippet into the question, so that you can run it and confirm that it is identical to the screenshot you linked to. Feel free to [edit] the snippet in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the fast reply. You are right. I have the following style "input[type='file'] {display: none;}" that I cannot remove because of another input form. How can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inner CSS style like this:

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  Select file to upload:
  <input type='file' name='fileToUploadNep' style="display:block" >
  <input type='submit' value='submit'></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe an error with your web browser.
The code is working perfectly on my web browser. Just tried it on Chrome web browser. I don't know why you added that semi-colon at the end of your code:

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  Select file to upload:
  <input type='file' name='fileToUploadNep'>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'></form>
```

**;**
The code is working properly. Ask the developer of your web browser.
[Screenshot, taken from my computer...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59O3o.png)
If you have another form on the web page and wants to hide one of it's input element, just simple `hidden` class to it and in your CSS file, add `.hidden{display: none}` and that's all!
or, the simplest way is to add an inline style to the input.file element. It'll override the style, written on your CSS file.
Sample: `<input type='file' name='fileToUploadNep' style="display: inline-block">`

Comment: Hi. thanks for the fast reply. You are right. I have the following style "input[type='file'] {display: none;}" that I cannot remove because of another input form. How can I solve my problem ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Hi. style="display: inline-block" does the job. Thank a lot :)